# Downsample time series whenever abs(difference) since the previous sample exceeds threshold

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, sampling, downsampling

I have a timeseries of intraday tick-by-tick stock prices that change gradually over time. Whenever there is a small change (e.g. the price increases by $0.01), a new row of data is created. This leads to a very large data series which is slow to plot. I want to downsample so that small changes (e.g. the price goes up/down/up/down/up/down and is unchanged after 50 rows of data) are ignored, which improves plotting speed without sacrificing the qualitative accuracy of the graph. I only want to sample if the price goes up/up/up/up so that I am only displaying obvious changes.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
prices = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,1000, size=(100, 1))/100+1000, columns=list('A'))
```

I wish to sample whenever the difference with the previous sample exceeds some threshold. So, I will sample row 0 by default. If row 1, 2, 3 and 4 are too close to row 0, I want to throw them away. Then, if row 5 is sufficiently far away from row 0, I will sample that. Then, row 5 becomes my new anchor point, and I will repeat the same process described immediately above.

Is there a way to do this, ideally without a loop?

Comment: `pd.DataFrame` fails for me.  `list('prices')` turns into `['p', 'r', 'i', 'c', 'e', 's']`.  `columns=['prices']` works.

Comment: @Jase Do you want to calculate it on history or real time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could apply a down-sampling masking function that checks if the distance has been exceeded.  Then use that to select to select the applicable rows.

Here is the down-sampling masking function:

```
def down_mask(x, max_dist=3):
    global cum_diff
    
    # if NaN return True
    if x!=x:
        return True
    
    cum_diff += x
    if abs(cum_diff) > max_dist:
        cum_diff = 0
        return True
    
    return False
```

Then apply it and use it as a mask to get the entries that you want:

```
cum_diff = 0

df[df['prices'].diff().apply(down_mask, max_dist=5)]

     prices
0   1002.07
1   1007.37
2   1000.09
6   1008.08
10  1001.57
14  1006.74
18  1000.42
19  1006.98
21  1001.30
26  1008.89
28  1003.77
38  1009.04
40  1000.52
44  1007.06
47  1001.21
48  1009.38
49  1001.81
51  1008.64
52  1002.72
55  1008.84
56  1000.86
57  1007.17
67  1001.31
68  1006.33
79  1001.14
98  1009.74
99  1000.53
```

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly what was asked for. I offer two options with a threshold and a threshold and a sliding period.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

prices = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,1000, size=(100, 1))/100+1000, columns=list('A'))

threshold_ = 3
index = np.abs(prices['A'].values[1:] - prices['A'].values[:-1]) > threshold_
index = np.insert(index, 0, True)

print(prices[index == True], len(prices[index == True]))

period = 5
hist = len(prices)
index = np.abs(prices['A'].values[period:] - prices['A'].values[:hist-period]) > threshold_
index = np.insert(index, 0, np.empty((1,period), dtype=bool)[0])

print(prices[index == True], len(prices[index == True]))
```